# Websphere 8 classloading

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere-8

I'm new to WebSphere. I'm trying to port a Wildfly application (a .ear) to WebSphere 8. When I deploy my application.ear on WebSphere I got a ClassNotFound exception about a class stored in a .jar that I put into the .ear/lib. Do I have to add some explicit dependencies? If so, how to do that? I tried indicating dependencies into .ear/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF without success. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a colleague, the problem was about the `<!DOCTYPE...>` on top of the application.xml. We removed

```
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, 
Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.2//EN" 
"http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/application_1_2.dtd">
```

and we added

```
<library-directory>lib</library-directory>
```

and the .ear deployed fine.